# Javascript amplitude image

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I have this script built with p5.js that checks the amplitude data of an audio file and reproduces that in an image, you can see the snippet here http://www.vtxfactory.org/p5/empty-example/

Here is the js:

```
var song, analyzer;

function preload() {
  img = loadImage("http://www.vtxfactory.org/images/vtxlogovnl.png");       
  song = loadSound("http://www.vtxfactory.org/sounds/masterflash.mp3");
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(250, 250);
  song.loop();

  // create a new Amplitude analyzer
  analyzer = new p5.Amplitude();

  // Patch the input to an volume analyzer
  analyzer.setInput(song);
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0, 0)

  // Get the average (root mean square) amplitude
  var rms = analyzer.getLevel();
  fill(0, 0, 0, 20);
  stroke(255, 255, 255);

  image(img, width/3, height/3, 10+rms*200, 10+rms*200);

}
```

How can I change the axis of the animation to the middle of the image?

Also, when the image amplifies and goes to normal size again, it let's some frames along the way, any way to improve that? I think it may have something to do with the background being formatted to be transparent, but I want to put this script over an image.

I have here some references for the code I'm trying to achieve https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/image

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used p5.js that much, but I'm pretty sure you can use the "translate(x,y)" function to transform from the middle of the image. The translate would then correspond to half of the width (x), and half of the height (y). I might have a go at coding it for you later. Let me know if solved it yourself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I've tried it but the result didn't change, I've put the translate(x,y) on function draw() but with no avail :/